# Examples where $1+I$ is inverted but $I$ is not mapped into the Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f:A\to B$ be a commutative ring morphism. Let $I\vartriangleleft A$ be an ideal. If $f(I)\subset \mathrm J(B)$ is contained in the Jacobson radical then $f(1+i)=1+f(i)\in B^\times$ is a unit so $1+I$ is inverted.

On the other hand, if $1+f(i)\in B^\times$ it does not seem to follow that $f(i)\in \mathrm J(B)$ since perhaps $1+bf(i)\notin B^\times$ for some $b\in B$.

**Question.** What are some examples where this implication fails i.e $f(1+I)\subset B^\times$ but $f(I)\nsubseteq\mathrm J(B)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some very basic examples. Let $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q$ be the inclusion map,
and let $I$ be any non-trivial ideal, but for argument's sake say $I=3\Bbb Z$.
Then $f(1+I)\subseteq\Bbb Q^\times$ but of course $J(\Bbb Q)=0$. Taking $I=3\Bbb Z$
we have another property: $1$ is the only invertible element of $1+I$ over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Just came up with that example myself, but maybe you could help me clarify the source of my confusion. Say $f$ *radicalizes $I$* if $f(I)\subset \mathrm J(B)$. The first paragraph of the question shows that if $f$ radicalizes $I$ then it inverts $1+I$. In this case, the universal property of localization gives a unique factorization of $f$ through $A[(1+I)^{-1}]$. A calculation shows this localization also radicalizes $I$, so it seems the localization represents the functor of radicalizations of $I$. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I think I see my error - radicalizations of $I$ are not functorial in the target ring. Thanks anyway!